# Change order of dump properties

Tags: c#, linqpad

the dump method prints the objects in the order of the class defintion. when i have a class inheritance, the proprties of the inherited class is below the properties of the parent class.
how to change the order so i can have child2 property between parent1 and parent2?

```
void Main()
{
    extendedchild a = new extendedchild();
    a.parent3 = DateTime.Now;

    a.Dump();
}

/// <summary>
/// This file holds all user defined indicator methods.
/// </summary>
public class parent
{


 
    public double parent1 { get; set; }

 
    public double parent2 { get; set; }

 
    public DateTime parent3 { get; set; }



}
public class extendedchild: parent
{
    
    public bool child1 { get; set; }

    public double child2 { get; set; }
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not a LinqPad user, but have you checked the LinqPad documentation about customizing dump? (https://www.linqpad.net/CustomizingDump.aspx) _(P.S.: I like the code example given in the section "Customizing Dump for Simple Types" which is not compilable because not all paths return a value there. Hehe...)_

Comment: there are methods to filter and manupulate properties. i dont see any method to shift the order of the properties.

Comment: According to the doc i linked, LinqPad allows to let the dump output being produced by your own code in a variety of ways. And if your code can produce the dump output, your code can obviously not only control what fields/properties/values/whatever is going to be included in the dump output, but also in whichever desired order. I don't understand why you would think that you can't change the order when LinqPad offers you to customize the dump in ways that give you full control of the dump output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize how an object is dumped by writing a `ToDump` method. Either add the `ToDump` method to the class itself, i.e., `extendedchild` in this case:

```
object ToDump() => new { parent1, child1, parent2, child2, parent3 };
```

or write a static `ToDump` method in the query (outside the classes) as follows:

```
static object ToDump (object x) => x is extendedchild c 
    ? new { c.parent1, c.child1, c.parent2, c.child2, c.parent3 }
    : x;
```